# How do you "restrict" a smooth tensor field to a point?

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors

I am confused about some aspects of the following definition.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ denote the commutative ring of smoth functions on $M$ and $C^{\infty}\left(TM\right)$ be the set of smoth vector fields on $M$ forming a module over $C^{\infty}\left(M\right).$ 
>   Put $C_0^{\infty}\left(TM\right)=C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ and for each positive integer $r$ let
>   $$C_r^{\infty}\left(TM\right)= C^{\infty}\left(TM\right) \otimes \ldots \otimes C^{\infty}\left(TM\right)$$
>   be $r$-fold tensor product of $C^{\infty}\left(TM\right)$ over $C^{\infty}\left(M\right).$
>
> **Definition:**
>   Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold. A smooth tensor field $T$ on $M$ of type $\left(r,s\right)$ is a map $T:C_r^{\infty}\left(TM\right) \rightarrow C_s^{\infty}\left(TM\right)$ which is multi-linear over $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ i.e.
>   $$T\left( X_1 \otimes \dots X_{k-1} \otimes \left( f.Y+g.Z \right) \otimes X_{k+1} \otimes \dots \otimes X_r \right) $$
>   $$=f.T\left( X_1 \otimes \dots X_{k-1} \otimes Y  \otimes X_{k+1} \otimes \dots \otimes X_r \right)+g.T\left( X_1 \otimes \dots X_{k-1} \otimes Z  \otimes X_{k+1} \otimes \dots \otimes X_r \right)$$
>   for all $X_1, \dots, X_r,Y,Z \in C^{\infty}\left(TM\right)$ and $f,g \in C^{\infty}\left(M\right).$
>
> Alternatively, we use the notation $T\left( X_1 , \dots , X_r \right)$ for $T\left( X_1 \otimes \dots \otimes X_r \right).$
>
> We denote the multi-linear restriction of $T$ to the $r-$fold tensor product $TM_p \otimes \dots \otimes TM_p$ of the vector space $TM_p$ over $\mathbb{R}$ by $T_p : \left( X_1\left( p \right) , \dots , X_r\left( p \right) \right)  \mapsto T\left( X_1 , \dots , X_r \right) \left(p\right). $

I cannot understand that why $T$ can be restricted to the $r-$fold tensor product $TM_p \otimes \dots \otimes TM_p$ of the vector space $TM_p$ over $\mathbb{R}.$ I am wondering what the domain of $T_p$ is? If its domain is $TM_p \otimes \dots \otimes TM_p$ then $C_r^{\infty}\left(TM\right)$ has to contain $TM_p \otimes \dots \otimes TM_p$? I do not know whether or not this is true?
On the other hand, if its domain is $C_r^{\infty}\left(T_pM\right)$ (we consider on tangent space not tangent bundle) then $C_r^{\infty}\left(T_pM\right)$ is a set of vector fields which go through $p$? However, it is necessary to define the Riemannian metric under $T_p$ which has domain is $T_pM \otimes T_pM.$

I should be very glad to recieve responses from anyone reading this who have comments or suggestions of decent!

Comment: There is *no* sensible reason for using exclamation marks in titles.

Comment: On the other hand, your question has nothing to do with riemannian manifolds. Picking a good title is the best way for you to attract attention from the proplee who know about the subject you are asking about. (Your question has nothing to do with general topology, or algebraic topology or riemann surfaced, either...()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed inaccurate to call $T_p$ the "restriction" of $T$, since $TM_p\otimes\dots\otimes TM_p$ is not a subset of $C^\infty_r(TM)$ in any natural way.  Instead, it is a quotient: given an element of $TM$, you can get an element of $TM_p$ by evaluating at $p$.  Given an element of $C^\infty_r(TM)$, you can then get an element of $TM_p\otimes\dots\otimes TM_p$ by evaluating each of the vector fields in your tensor at $p$.

So if it doesn't make sense to restrict $T$, how is $T_p$ defined?  The answer is as follows.  Suppose $v_1,\dots,v_r\in TM_p$.  Then we can choose vector fields $X_1,\dots,X_r\in TM$ such that $X_i(p)=v_i$ for $i=1,\dots,r$.  We then define $$T_p(v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_r)=T(X_1\otimes\dots\otimes X_r)(p).$$  (And if you check that this is multilinear in $v_1,\dots,v_r$, this uniquely extends to a map $T_p$ defined on $TM_p\otimes\dots\otimes TM_p$.)

Now, there's an obvious problem with this definition: there are lots of different choices of $X_1,\dots,X_r$ you could make, and it's not obvious that the definition of $T_p(v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_r)$ ends up being the same no matter what choices you make.  However, it turns out that the choice of $X_1,\dots X_r$ doesn't make a difference, because of the assumption that $T$ is $C^\infty(M)$-linear.  For simplicity, let me illustrate how this works in the case $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $r=1$; the general case is similar but more complicated.

So we have a tangent vector $v\in TM_p$, and want to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are two vector fields such that $X(p)=Y(p)=v$, then $T(X)(p)=T(Y)(p)$ (so that we can define $T_p(v)=T(X)(p)$ and this won't depend on the choice of $X$).  Let $Z=X-Y$, so $Z(p)=0$; it suffices to show that $T(Z)(p)=0$.  Now since we are assuming $M=\mathbb{R}$, we can think of this vector field $Z$ as just a smooth function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Now define $W(t)=Z(t)/(t-p)$ for $t\neq 0$ and $W(p)=Z'(p)$.  Since $Z$ is smooth and $Z(p)=0$, $W$ is also smooth, and we have $Z=f\cdot W$, where $f(t)=t-p$.

Now we use the $C^\infty(M)$-linearity of $T$.  Since $Z=f\cdot W$, $T(Z)=f\cdot T(W).$  Evaluating at $p$, we get $T(Z)(p)=f(p)T(W)(p)$.  But $f(p)=p-p=0$, so we conclude that $T(Z)(p)=0$, as desired.

(When $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ rather than just $\mathbb{R}$, you need to use [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard's_lemma) to get an expression analogous to this expression $Z=f\cdot W$ in order to show that $T(Z)(p)=0$: if $p=(p_1,\dots,p_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then it is possible to find $W_1,\dots,W_n$ such that $$Z(t_1,\dots,t_n)=(t_1-p_1)W_1(t_1,\dots,t_n)+\dots+(t_n-p_n)W_n(t_1,\dots,t_n).$$  In the case that $M$ is a general manifold, you need to use a bump function on a coordinate chart near $p$ to reduce to the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: oh! I see it now. thank you so much!